# Any way to have multiple counts within same SQL query?

Tags: sql, count

What is the most elegant/efficient way to check multiple different `count()`'s with different conditions within the same statement? Given the syntax of SQL, it appears that I can only have one count() statement with each set of `WHERE`/`HAVING` conditionals within my query. Therefore, to utilize a different set of `WHERE`/`HAVING` conditionals, it seems this second count(*) needs to be in a different select statement. Is the best way to put this into the same result set to `UNION` them? Is there any alternative?
Ideally I could do something like:

```
SELECT count(*) as First, count(*) as Second  
FROM table  
WHERE --conditionals for First  
AND  
--conditionals for Second
```

But I think this is impossible. Is the only way to do it to `UNION` two separate queries?

Comment: What you want here is a case expression. `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN //conditionals THEN 1 END), COUNT(CASE WHEN //conditionals THEN 1 END) as Second FROM table;`

Comment: You would use ***conditional aggregation*** where `COUNT` is implemented as `SUM(CASE WHEN ... 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: You can combine conditional aggregation (`SUM+CASE`) with window frames (`OVER`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical method uses `case` with an aggregation function:

```
select sum(case when condition1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when condition2 then 1 else 0 end)
```

The SQL Standard method uses `filter`:

```
select count(*) filter (where condition1),
       count(*) filter (where condition2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most efficient but you could use sub-queries:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Count (*) FROM table WHERE <conditionals for First> ) As First,
    (SELECT Count (*) FROM table WHERE <conditionals for Second>) As Second
```